# vscode workspace can use relative path

Tags: visual-studio-code, pawn

I want to make a AMX mod X script, this modules are related which game I make, so I am using workspace as configuration. Making compiler, library and output path dependent of each game.
my source code has same folder as compiler

I've tried to write `./` and `.\\` but it's won't work, vscode still can't find `amxxpc.exe`, here's my configuration workspace:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "amxxpawn.compiler.executablePath": "./amxxpc.exe",
        "amxxpawn.compiler.includePaths": [
            "./include"
        ],
        "amxxpawn.compiler.outputPath": "../plugins",
        "amxxpawn.compiler.outputType": "path"
    }
}
```

`amxxpawn.compiler.executablePath` still can't figure amxxpc.exe until I wrote full path. since this placed in same folder as source code, I also tried to remove `./` but still can't find it.

here's my extension I use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KliPPy.amxxpawn-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not always work in every extension but I moved every configs in workspace settings to `user.json` and then use `${workspaceFolder}` as relative variable, for e.x:

```
"amxxpawn.compiler.includePaths": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/include"
        ]
```

workspace still used but I left it `folder` and `path` alone, also making `path` value to `.` means location of `workspace` file